# NextJs not returning the serversiderenderingprops for "/" url

Tags: next.js, getserversideprops

I've started working with Nextjs with the purpose of server-side-rendering so that I can feed dynamic values to metatags for each URL. [ reactjs doesn't work easily here ].

Now In Nextjs, I'm trying to load all the data from Firebase and show a few of them on the home page.

this is the error I'm getting if trying to use props in home(props).

```
'props' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133)
Parameter 'props' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7006)
(parameter) props: any
```

The page Structure: [Page Structure Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yY8uH.png)

Index.tsx file: this ll be rendered on this URL: localhost://3000

```
import React from "react"
import Head from "next/head"
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import styles from '@/styles/Home.module.css'
import { useState } from 'react'
import {colRef, collection,db,getDocs,query,orderBy} from '../firebase/clientApp'


 function Home() {
  // Not able to use props here, which get returned form serverside props.
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>title goes here</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <main>
        <p>rendering home page</p>
      </main>
    </>
  )
}

export async function getServerSideProps(){
  // const [blogs,setBlogs]=useState([{}]);
  const dbCollection =  collection(db, 'blogs');
  const q=query(dbCollection,orderBy('Time','desc'));
  const datasnap = await getDocs(q);
  // console.log("data snap docs"+datasnap.docs);
  const data = datasnap.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
  // console.log(data);
  data.forEach(item=>{
  // console.log("item time "+item.Time+"\n")
  // console.log("item body: "+item.body+"\n")
        var curObj={
          Title:item.Title,
          body:item.body,
          id:item.id,
          excerpts:item.excerpts,
          clip:item.clip,
          posted_by:item.posted_by,
          Time:item.Time.toDate().toDateString(),
          imageSrc:item.imageSrc
        }
        // if(curObj.imageSrc===""){
        //   curObj.imageSrc=`${imageSrc}`
        // }
        // setBlogs(blogs=>[...blogs,curObj])
  })
    // console.log(data);
  return{
    props:{key:"props returned from serversideprops"}
  }
}


export default Home
```

I see this on specs: serversideProps can only be exported from a page. You can’t export it from non-page files.

but not sure if this is the mistake I'm doing.. or if we have any other solution for this.

thanks,